# Giving a data frame a title and styling columns with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, format

I want to give `dict_val` dataframe a title that is placed in the center `title`. I am also trying to separate the each 3 digits with a comma on the `Numbers` column how would I be able to give a dataframe a title and style the a column as such and get the Expected Output below?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

title = 'Number and Numbers 2 Comparison'
numbers = np.array([123242737.4923,679754672.3849]) 
numbers2 = np.array([123523,467895]) 

dict_val = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':numbers.round(2),'Numbers 2': numbers2})
display(dict_val)
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

```
  Number and Numbers 2 Comparison
    Numbers         Numbers 2
0   123,242,737.49  123523
1   679,754,672.38  467895
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Styler.format`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html):

```
dict_val.style.format(formatter={'Numbers': '{:,.2f}'})
```

Create `MultiIndex` and set styles for alignment to center:

```
text = 'Number and Numbers 2 Comparison'

dict_val.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[text], dict_val.columns])
print (dict_val)
  Number and Numbers 2 Comparison          
                          Numbers Numbers 2
0                    1.232427e+08    123523
1                    6.797547e+08    467895

css = [ {'selector': 'th.col_heading.level0', 'props': 'text-align: center;'}]
dict_val.style.set_table_styles(css, overwrite=False).format(formatter={(text, 'Numbers'): '{:,.2f}'})
```

Comment: thank you that works is there a way I could place the a title and center it on top of the columns

Comment: @georgehere - In excel file?

Comment: No I just want to place a title for the data frame it is the variable `title`. When done `display(dict_val)` it should have the title and then the columns at the bottom just like the expected output

Comment: @georgehere - answer was edited.

Comment: Sorry for giving too much trouble but the column names are not on top of the values  unfortunately how would I be able to fix that, the column names `Numbers and Numbers 2` are a little bit more to the right.  I have posted a screenshot of the edited post above

Comment: @georgehere Now I am offline, on phone only, possible solution is add padding css to header,  hard to know if working.